# WebApi return wrong datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am sending simple query to the Microsoft CRM 
through the HttpClient, but in result i can see that datetime field has wrong value. 
In CRM this field has GMT +02:00 timezone, and I am in  UTC +1. 
Now, let say that I have in CRM datetime value 2.2.2017 3:30PM, when I run HttpClient query through the web api, then i get the value 2.2.2017 11:30AM. So even if I convert it to the local time value will be wrong.

Is there same HttpClient setup, where I am making mistake?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Microsoft CRM but it doesn't seem likely that the issue is with the HttpClient. Are there any other timezone configuraitons to take into account? Perhaps you need to adjust the timezone for your SQL Server instance?

Comment: FYI, CRM stores date as UTC in DB. While creating date ll be converted, while querying utc returns

Comment: Were you able to sort it out?

Comment: No, its really strange. Its like CRM not return time in UTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be in different timezone, the record might be created by an user with different timezone settings. Hence CRM will store it in Offset. Then while returning using SDK query, you have to manipulate the required result.

Really you have to [understand](http://dynamicscrmcoe.com/behaviors-date-time-fields-few-concerns/) how CRM datetime works.

> Date Time stored in DB: UTC
>   Date Time shown in CRM UI: Local Time Zone
>   (Even for Date Only format fields, time zone conversion is applied)
>
> Data Time fields retrieved through API: UTC
>   Date Time retrieve through filtered views: Local Time Zone

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn996866.aspx#Anchor_1) can help you to verify your CRM customizations & settings, then come to conclusion of what you are experiencing.